Do additional boundary conditions affect the compact embedding of Sobolev spaces?
Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ open bounded and sufficiently smooth with outward unit normal $\mathbf{n}$.
It is known by the Rellich-Kondrachov theorem that
$$ H^2(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^1(\Omega) \quad \text{compactly}.$$
Define a space $V_1 = \{ v \in H^2(\Omega) \quad \text{s.t } \Delta v =0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega \}.$ Can we immediately deduce that $ V_1 \hookrightarrow H^1(\Omega)\text{ compactly}$?
In the same spirit, we also know that
$$ H^3(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^2(\Omega) \quad \text{compactly}.$$
However, it is not true that
$$ H^3(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^2_0(\Omega) \quad \text{compactly}.$$
Because there are definitely some functions in $H^3(\Omega)$ which do not vanish on the boundary. But, can we say that $H^3(\Omega) \cap H^2_0(\Omega) \hookrightarrow H^2_0(\Omega)\text{ compactly}$?
Note: The definition of $H^2_0(\Omega)$ is $\{ v \in H^2(\Omega) \quad \text{s.t } v = \nabla v \cdot \mathbf{n} =0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega \}$.

This boils down to the statement that the restriction of a compact operator to a subspace is also compact.
